# How can I get rid of internal contours? python

Tags: opencv, find, contour, area

I'm localizing light polluted areas in a photo from a satellite using cv2.findContours. Many of them are not entirely pollute internally, what I mean by that is they have black holes inside of them which shouldn't be considered part of the contours neither separate contours since I'm only contouring light polluted areas. When I started indexing the contours by size I noticed the black holes were treated as separate contours.

Processed image
[image: image description]

As you can see, for example #0, #67 and #64 are classified as contoured areas even though they shouldn't be

To find the contours I'm using

```
# Reading image
image_orig = cv2.imread("india_night.jpg")
# Processing to make contours smoother
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_gray, (5, 5), 0)
image_blurred = cv2.dilate(image_blurred, None)
_, image_threshold = cv2.threshold(image_blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
#sorting contours by size
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image_threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
```

My goal is to not classify these unpolluted areas as polluted ones

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do it by looking at hierarchy. Basically if you are passing cv2.RETR_TREE than hierarchy different from -1 would mean that this contour is inside other one

```
_, contours, hierarchy  = cv2.findContours(image_gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for i in range(len(contours)):
    if hierarchy[0,i,3] == -1:
        cv2.drawContours(image_orig, contours, i, (0, 255, 0))
```

This would result with only outer contours being drawn like on the image below 
[image]

EDIT:
So what if you need to exclude inner parts of your shape. Now this is not the most optimal solution but I think it would give you good view on how hierarchy works:

[image]

```
for i in range(len(contours)):
    if hierarchy[0, i, 3] == -1:    # this is the outer contour which we need to draw
        cv2.drawContours(image_orig, contours, i, (0, 255, 0), -1)
        if hierarchy[0, i, 2] != -1:    # if this contour has inner contours
            childrenIndex = hierarchy[0, i, 2]
            while hierarchy[0, childrenIndex, 0] != -1:  # get all children for the outer contour
                childrenIndex = hierarchy[0, childrenIndex, 0]
                # now the first inner contour is just near the outer one (from the opposite side of the line)
                # thats why we are drawing that inner contour's children
                if hierarchy[0, childrenIndex, 2] != -1:
                    cv2.drawContours(image_orig, contours, hierarchy[0, childrenIndex, 2], (0, 0, 255), -1)
```

You can also read [opencv hierarchy tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) for a better understanding of how it works

Comment: But what if I need the average brightness of the outer area? This way looks like it will give me the avrage brightness of the outer area + inner area

Comment: @Krulg I've updated my answer to solve that problem too.